# Can selenium post real traffic on a website?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, web-traffic

I have written a script in selenium python which is basically opening up a website and clicking on links in it and doing this thing multiple times..
Purpose of the software was to increase traffic on the website but after script was made it has observed that is not posting real traffic on website while website is just taking it as a test and ignoring it.

Now I am wondering whether it is basically possible with selenium or not? 
I have searched around and I suppose it is possible but don't know how. Do anyone know about this? Or is there any specific piece of code for this?

Comment: When you say the "Purpose of the software was to increase traffic on the website", what do you mean? You are trying to inflate traffic numbers?  You are trying to load test the site? What's the website and are you allowed to programatically generate traffic on it?

Answer (score -2):

It does create traffic, the problem is websites sometimes defends from bots and can guess if the income connection is a bot or not, maybe you should put some time.wait(seconds) between actions to deceive the website control and make it thinks you are a person